# how to change bootstrap dropdown :before triangle to different shape

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

After a bit of research I came to know the small triangle in the drop down menu comes from the `:before pseudo class`. But when I try to change the shape of it, it doesn't change no matter what I do. I want to make it like a thick line connecting my dropdown to dropdown menu. is it possible to achieve? I want to achieve something like this in the picture.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
...
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq5Ef/) and the triangle i am referring to.  [image]

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change the border colors and styles to modify that triangle's appearance.  Bootstrap is using the borders to shape it.  As an example, here is a fiddle with a thick gray line connecting the header and the dropdown menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/freginold/o0zuq7Lv/1/

You can change the color however you want, as well as the thickness of the line, by playing with the `:before` and `:after` styles.

UPDATE: To add your own icon/character, use the `dropdown-menu` styles adjusted like they are in this fiddle to thin the borders and widen the interior area:

http://jsfiddle.net/freginold/o0zuq7Lv/3/

Comment: yes that'more like what i wanted. But is there anyway i can do exactkly like that picture. cause the suggested method doesn't wrap around the menu(3 dots)

Comment: @NaveenKumar Have you tried inserting the three dots as an image, in the `content` attribute?

Comment: It is not a image. its font awesome icon

Comment: @NaveenKumar that might be a bit harder.  I'll try to play around with it.

Comment: @NaveenKumar You can do it like it's set up in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/freginold/o0zuq7Lv/3/) -- just replace the pipe (|) with your Font Awesome icon.